# Error Running yii migrate after cloning

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii-migrations

I'm using the basic template for Yii2. I created the project and uploaded it to github so other devs can clone and start contributing.

After cloning and running composer install, I'm getting this error when I try to run yii migrate.

```
λ php yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.8)

Total 1 new migration to be applied:
        m160704_071418_user_table

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m160704_071418_user_table
PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'm160704_071418_user_table' not found'

in C:\wamp\www\miespacio\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\MigrateController.php:170

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

My question is: Is there any steps I'm missing to make this work? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Potentially useful information: I can create new migrations and run them just fine after cloning. The problem is running existing migrations.

Comment: Have you changed the names of your files? The file name and class name must be identical for it to work.

Comment: just try to reinstall project from composer again. And do not change migrations names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create migration by `yii migrate/create <migration-name>` command. And don't change file name or class name of migrations.

Example: create migration add test table

`yii migrate/create create_test_table`

After run that command, you will have a php file in `@app/migrations`

Filename: `m160704_110735_create_test_table.php`

Code generator:

```
<?php

use yii\db\Migration;

/**
 * Handles the creation for table `test_table`.
 */
class m160704_110735_create_test_table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('test_table', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('test_table');
    }
}
```

Remember: don't change filename or class name.

Goodluck and have fun!

Comment: This answer prompted me the check the class name and sure enough it differed from the name of the file. I updated the class name to match the file name and I'm back in business. Thank you all.